# No shared Datasets in solution explorer of business intelligence development studio

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008, ssrs-2008, bids

I have business intelligence development studio v 9.0 installed and am trying to create some sample reports. in my solution explorer there is no shared Datasets folder so that i can add or cread .rsd files

anyone knows how to add the shared datasets to the solution explorer of the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

only sql server 2008 R2 has shared dataset the first version of 2008 doesn't have this feature.